# Github action push java artifact to github repo

Tags: maven, github, dockerfile, github-actions

I have a Github repo project using GitHub actions with a docker file used to build the SpringBoot Java project.
I want to download packages from the Github repo for custom artifacts from GitHub repo and also be able upload artifact to it.

So I followed the link [Configuring Apache Maven for use with GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-apache-maven-for-use-with-github-packages) by adding the section to a settings.xml file:

```
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>github</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>github</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>github</id>
          <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
          <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>

  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>github</id>
      <username>USERNAME</username>
      <password>${GITHUB_TOKEN}</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

To publish the package from the dockerfile build I added the following to my pom.xml:

```
 <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>github</id>
        <name>GitHub OWNER Apache Maven Packages</name>
        <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

The following is the content of my dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk10 as build
WORKDIR /app
ADD pom.xml /app/pom.xml
ADD src /app/src    
ADD settings.xml /root/.m2/settings.xml
RUN ["mvn", "clean", "install", "deploy"]
```

Is it possible to deploy from the dockerfile to Github repo?  Somehow the deploy piece does not seem to work.  I have tried few times but not sure what's wrong with my sections.
Currently this is my error in my docker build:

> Could not transfer metadata
> com.chg.sa:demo-sa-java-service:1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> from/to github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY): Not
> authorized -> [Help 1]

Comment: Are you trying to upload a package or an artifact? Artifacts are workflow-level, packages are repo-level.
Also - you have set the owner and repository values to your repo...right?

Answer (score 0):

I got the push working using Dockerfile building by passing in the github token as build arg and switching the owner and repo name to their values.